# Sort array to get values in loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have below array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["download_subcategory_name"]=>
    string(17) "Application Forms"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["download_subcategory_name"]=>
    string(21) "Service Related Forms"
  }
}
```

My problem is how to sort this array in loop to get values.

Comment: My problem is how to sort this array ? My problem is how to to get values? In both cases, it is not a question

Comment: thanks @splash58.. then should i start my question like "MY QUESTION IS how to sort this array??"

Comment: I do not see any sorting of an array in the answer. Am I wrong? You have just written simple example of using foreach, IMHO :)

Comment: @splash58 i am still working on the same problem.. I thought below code will solve the issue.. but it didnt.. if you have any idea about the question please help to solve the same..

Comment: I asked you : My problem is how to sort this array ? My problem is how to to get values? Now, you can get value, as i see :) Do you want sorting such array? By what rules? There is no problem in your question up now

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer..

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    echo $values['download_subcategory_name'] , '<br/>';
}
```